# Angular formly only shows blank page when printing form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, printing, angular-formly

I am attempting to create a button where a user can print the page for their records, but it keeps showing up blank using formly, I'm assuming because the form is being generated dynamically.  I am using a print directive in the Print button:

```
    (function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    function printDirective() {
        var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');
        // if there is no printing section, create one
        if (!printSection) {
            printSection = document.createElement('div');
            printSection.id = 'printSection';
            document.body.appendChild(printSection);
        }
        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on('click', function () {
                var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(attrs.printElementId);
                if (elemToPrint) {
                    printElement(elemToPrint);
                }
            });
            window.onafterprint = function () {
                // clean the print section before adding new content
                printSection.innerHTML = '';
            }
        }
        function printElement(elem) {
            // clones the element you want to print
            var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
            printSection.appendChild(domClone);
            window.print();
        }
        return {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };
    }
    angular.module('formlyApp').directive('ngPrint', [printDirective]);
}(window.angular));
```

and here is the print button:

```
<button class="btn btnSubmit" type="submit" ng-print  print-element-id="printSection" ng-hide="vm.iForm.$invalid">Print and Save</button>
```

The print window pops up when I press the button, but the page is blank other than showing the Name of the page and date.  How can I get formly fields to print out?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [angularPrint](https://github.com/samwiseduzer/angularPrint). It makes it super easy.